# Вывод элементов в несколько столбцов

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview

Всем привет.
В моем приложении используется горизонтальный ресайклервью. Проблема - мне нужно выводить элементы не в 1 строку, а в несколько. При этом в первой строке может быть 2 элемента, а во второй 3 элемента. Обычный Grid сюда, думаю, не подойдет, ведь он "выстраивает" статичное количество столбцов

Comment: Попробуйте написать свой layoutmanager